# Centos services cannot bind on localhost but find on * or specific ip address

Tags: centos, vps, localhost

I've got a VPS with Centos 6.4 installed.
I used to have a VPS at Digital Ocean that when I start PostgreSQL or Monit that bind to localhost, they all work fine. 
But on the new VPS, when I have PostgreSQL listen to "localhost", PostgreSQL is saying:

```
WARNING: could not create listen socket for "localhost"
```

And Monit, when I tell Monit to listen on "localhost", Monit is saying:

```
http server: Could not create a server socket at port 2812 -- Cannot assign requested address
```

I wonder what could be wrong on my VPS that lead to such behavior. If I have PostgreSQL listen on '*' instead of "localhost" then it runs just fine.

**Update**:

My `ifconfig -a`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:0A:01:3D
          inet addr:xxx.xx.xxx.xxx  Bcast:103.27.236.127  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe0a:13d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:198875 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:49492 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:135854898 (129.5 MiB)  TX bytes:7779876 (7.4 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          LOOPBACK  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

My `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 CentOS64
::1             localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

Comment: Is the `lo` interface up?

Comment: Look at your /etc/hosts file. Is there an entry for localhost for 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I think so. I updated my `ifconfig -a`

Comment: @dmourati I do have 127.0.0.1 for localhost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `lo` interface is down. Note that it explicitly does *not* say it is `UP` and does not have its associated IP address of 127.0.0.1. I have no idea how that would have happened, as this should always be brought up.

If the `lo` interface is down, no programs can bind or connect to localhost.

Bring it up yourself:

```
ifup lo
```

Comment: You saved my day man. I'm trying to figuring out why it's down.